# Flutter Sqflite open database needs join method

Tags: flutter, sqflite

I am currently trying to implement SQLite to my flutter project and I don't know how to open a database because the examples from SQLite seems to use an older version.
In the examples, they use a string path in the openDatabase() method but in my version, the method needs a `join(await getDatabasePath())`. But when I input this in the method android studio editor shows red lines and the await keyword is not getting recognized. Can someone post an example that is working? I am using SQLite 1.1.5

Comment: You have to add `async` modifire to your method otherwise await will not available in that scope.

Comment: https://pub.dev/documentation/path/latest/path/join.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the responses. It seems that there was a problem with my sqflite dependency. After running packages upgrade it works as expected.

Comment: `Future<void> createDB() async {

    var databasesPath = await getDatabasesPath();
    String path = join(databasesPath, Constants.MY_DB);

    final Future<Database> database = openDatabase(
      path,...);
}`
my version

Answer (score 0):

> In case you have not added this [path](https://pub.dev/packages/path/install) plugin in your project make
> sure to add it in order to import the method properly.

Open **pubspec** file and import the path plugin like this

```
dependencies:
  path: ^1.8.3
```

Then import like this.

```
import 'package:path/path.dart';
```